# How to turn and centre a coordinate system in R

Tags: r

would really appreciate help with this one. I'm new to programming, but adamant on learning. I use R (studio).

I have X and Y coordinates along a thin, bending line (a miroorganism flagellum) at discrete time steps. I have essentially tracked the flagellum over time. The data look like this:

---

Slice   X    Y

750    180  178

750    189  172

750    X3   Y3

750    X4   Y4

751    X5   Y5

751    X6   Y6

751  X7   Y7

751 X8   Y8

752 X9   Y9

..... Xn   Yn

---

The first column (slice) is the timestep, so I have a number (not always the same number, though) of X,Y coordinates for each timestep. Here's an image of what it can look like:

[Data representation. Each line is defined by a number (10-15) discrete [X,Y] coordinates. The different lines are the different 'slices'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HTkn.jpg)

**Now, I would like to do several things:**

1. Centre around (move all data to) the average of all the first [X,Y] coordinates. That is, the average of the [X, Y] coordinates taken every time the slice number changes.
2. Rotate the entire dataset by the average angle defined by the straight line between the first and last set of data for each 'Slice', so that the first data point for each slice starts around [0,0] and subsequent data points fluctuate around the X axis in the positive X direction.

While the data are of course specific to my case, the issue of centering and turning the coordinate system is certainly a more general one. I guess I need to do a for loop, but i get stuck at identifying and extracting the [X,Y] coordinates based on the 'Slice' number.

I have put the data here, in case anyone is interested in helping: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6791606/Flagellum%20track%200012%20100fps%20-%20converted.csv

I really hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an elegant way to preform this without any loops.
In general, avoid looping in R as much as you can, you have dedicated functions which are much more efficient.
I recommend mastering `tidyr` for data manipulation.

```
library(tidyr)
library(readr)
flag.rotation <- flag.centered %>%
                 group_by(Slice) %>%
                 summarize(f.x = first(X), f.y = first(Y),
                           l.x = last(X), l.y = last(Y)) %>%
                 mutate(rot.ang = atan((l.y-f.y)/(l.x-f.x))) %>%
                 select(rot.ang)

rotate.ang <- -mean(flag.rotation$rot.ang)
```

This gives you the angle you want to rotate by (in your sample this is roughly 0.97 radians). Then, to actually rotate the data, use:

```
flag.rotated <- flagellum %>%
                mutate(rot.X = cos(rotate.ang)*X - sin(rotate.ang)*Y,
                rot.Y = sin(rotate.ang)*X + cos(rotate.ang)*Y) %>%
                select(Slice, rot.X, rot.Y)
```

For centering, first find the centers:

```
flag.center <- flag.rotated %>%
               group_by(Slice) %>%
               mutate(f.rot.X = first(rot.X), f.rot.Y = first(rot.Y)) %>%
               select(Slice, f.rot.X, f.rot.Y) %>%
               unique() %>%
               ungroup() %>%
               select(f.rot.X, f.rot.Y) %>%
               summarize(mean.f.X = mean(f.rot.X), mean.f.Y = mean(f.rot.Y))
```

The center (of the already rotated data) is now contained in `flag.center`. Now we can use this to center the rotated data:

```
flag.centered <- flag.rotated %>%
                 mutate(X = rot.X - flag.center$mean.f.X, Y = rot.Y - flag.center$mean.f.Y) %>%
                 select(X, Y, Slice)
```

This results in the following plot (the data points are at 50% transparency and the line is a "loess" smoothed line):
[image: Updated flagella plot - rotated and centered]
You can produce it using `ggplot2`:

```
# For producing the smoothed plot I used:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(flag.centered, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(Slice)), alpha = 0.5) + 
  stat_smooth(aes(color = factor(Slice)), se = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, seems more advanced and something I will certainly look into. However, it seems to me, the code centers the data around the glabal average of all X's and Y's. That is not exactly what I need. I need to center around the average of only the first X and Y for each slice.

Comment: Also, the rotation seems a little off from what I desire. I need the center  line of the data to align with the X-axis. I planned to calculate the rotation as this: For each 'slice', compute the angle of the line between the first and the last [X,Y] sets. Then take an average of these angles, and use this average to turn the whole dataset.

Comment: @LasseTorNielsen, I fixed the rotation and centering. I also split the code to segments to clarify the different states the "data is going through". 
For future reference - when submitting a question, please provide an original data set and a **should look like** data set (what the result should be for the sample you provide).  Otherwise, it's hard to understand the meaning.

Comment: Also, you should avoid `for` loops as much as you can. The `tidyr` approach is much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

**EDIT** Now including change in angle + ggplot code by Adi Sarid

```
df=read.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6791606/Flagellum%20track%200012%20100fps%20-%20converted.csv",header=T)

start_x=c()
start_y=c()
slice_id=c()
angle=c()

for(i in 1:length(unique(df$Slice))) {
  sl = df[df$Slice==unique(df$Slice)[i],]
  slice_id = unique(df$Slice)[i]
  start_x[i] = sl[1,2]
  start_y[i] = sl[1,3]
  angle[i] = -atan((sl[1,3]-tail(sl,1)[,3])/(sl[1,2]-tail(sl,1)[,2]))
}

gl_mean_x = mean(start_x)
gl_mean_y = mean(start_y)
gl_mean_angle = mean(angle)

df$X_center = df$X-gl_mean_x
df$Y_center = df$Y-gl_mean_y

## compute mean angle / create new score
alpha = gl_mean_angle
rotm <- matrix(c(cos(alpha),sin(alpha),-sin(alpha),cos(alpha)),ncol=2)
M = cbind(df$X_center,df$Y_center)

M2 <- t(rotm %*% (
t(M)-c(M[1,1],M[1,2])
)+c(M[1,1],M[1,2]))

df$X_center_angle = M2[,1]
df$Y_center_angle = M2[,2]

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = X_center_angle, y = Y_center_angle)) + 
geom_line(aes(color = factor(Slice))) + 
stat_smooth(aes(color = factor(Slice)), se = FALSE)
```

I did not fully understand your requirements so let me know if this works. Also, you might want to add a model to take care of the curve lines

Comment: Thanks, this seems to solve the first part of my problem, i.e. to identify the first instance of each 'Slice' number, to average the X and Y values of these, and to move the coordinates relative to this average. I still need to rotate the data, though, so that the centre-axis of the data aligns with the X-axis. Maybe I'm not very good at explaining it :)